# Google Drive Api result.getStatus().isSuccess() always true

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm managing the callback this way but the result is always success when it shouldn't.

Example:

- I search a file that doesn't exist and it doesn't show the log
- I search a file when disconnected from the internet and still it doesn't show the log
- Even if i create a file on drive when disconnected from the internet and set a callback for its creation, the result is success.

Here is the callback code

```
    ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> searchCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "cant open file");
                }

            }
        };
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android API has offline support, so performing an operation while offline will not fail.  Instead, any changes are queued up to occur when the device comes back online.

Similarly, searching for something that doesn't exist doesn't fail, it just returns an empty result.

You handling of success looks fine, you just aren't testing cases that will actually fail.